# Why I can not get the same string after using `seekg`?

Tags: c++, fstream, getline, seekg

I am tring to use `seekg` to move the `pos` and then read a line from the `.txt`.
However, I can not get the same string(a completed line) after using `seekp`, though the `pos` is same.

The `compiler` is MinGW 11.2.0 64-bit on x86 windows 11

Here is the `test.txt`

```
2   33.10   30.10   29.90   33.00   33.20   33.00   32.90   33.10   40.20   40.20   40.00   39.90   40.30   37.20   40.30   36.70
4   33.00   30.10   29.90   33.00   33.10   32.90   32.90   33.00   40.30   40.20   40.00   40.00   40.30   37.30   40.20   36.70
6   33.00   30.10   29.90   33.00   33.10   33.00   32.90   33.00   40.20   40.30   40.10   40.00   40.20   37.20   40.10   36.90
```

Here is my code.

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
string file_path = "./test.txt";
string s;
// don't use seekg
fstream f(file_path);
    getline(f, s);
    int p = f.tellg();
    cout << "the cur pos is:" << p << endl;
    getline(f, s);
    cout << s << endl;
    getline(f, s);
    cout << s << endl;
    f.close();

// use seekg
    fstream t(file_path);
    t.seekg(p, ios::beg);
    p = t.tellg();
    cout << "the cur pos is:" << p << endl;
    getline(t, s);
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

And the `output`

```
the cur pos is:139
2   33.10   30.10   29.90   33.00   33.20   33.00   32.90   33.10   40.20   40.20   40.00   39.90   40.30   37.20   40.30   36.70
4   33.00   30.10   29.90   33.00   33.10   32.90   32.90   33.00   40.30   40.20   40.00   40.00   40.30   37.30   40.20   36.70
the cur pos is:139
2.90    33.10   40.20   40.20   40.00   39.90   40.30   37.20   40.30   36.70
```

For supplement, here is the `string s` in memory.

```
2\t33.10\t30.10\t29.90\t33.00\t33.20\t33.00\t32.90\t33.10\t40.20\t40.20\t40.00\t39.90\t40.30\t37.20\t40.30\t36.70

4\t33.00\t30.10\t29.90\t33.00\t33.10\t32.90\t32.90\t33.00\t40.30\t40.20\t40.00\t40.00\t40.30\t37.30\t40.20\t36.70

2.90\t33.10\t40.20\t40.20\t40.00\t39.90\t40.30\t37.20\t40.30\t36.70
```

I don't know if it's the problem that there are `\t`s in the string.

So how can I solve this problem and get a completed line using `seekg`? It would be appreciated if someone can give me a hand.

Comment: Could you please present a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) So we have something we can copy'n'paste, compile, run and reproduce? That makes it a *lot* easier to [debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) the code and help you.

Comment: Ok, I'll do this.@JesperJuhl

Comment: I create `test.txt` with the data you gave and copy your source to `test.cc`, compile as `$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -O3 test.cc` and then run `$ ./a.out` I get this output: `the cur pos is:130
4   33.00   30.10   29.90   33.00   33.10   32.90   32.90   33.00   40.30   40.20   40.00   40.00   40.30   37.30   40.20   36.70
6   33.00   30.10   29.90   33.00   33.10   33.00   32.90   33.00   40.20   40.30   40.10   40.00   40.20   37.20   40.10   36.90
the cur pos is:130
4   33.00   30.10   29.90   33.00   33.10   32.90   32.90   33.00   40.30   40.20   40.00   40.00   40.30   37.30   40.20   36.70`

Comment: It's weird. You get the output that I need, maybe there is something else wrong with my code. Thanks for your test!@JesperJuhl

Comment: What compiler are you using? What compiler version? What build flags? What operating system?
I'm using `g++ (GCC) 13.1.1 20230429` with `-Wall -Wextra -O3` on Arch Linux. Don't answer in a comment, edit your question to add that extra info.

Comment: I also tried building your code with both address sanitizer and undefined behaviour sanitizer and none of those complained either.

Comment: I don't think it is relevant, but I *do* see one difference between the two halfs of your code; you explicitly `f.close();` but you don't do so for the `t` stream - it shouldn't matter since the stream will be `close()`d on destruction, but as a wild guess, maybe try making both explicitly close the stream?

Comment: Actually, once I called the `f.close()` and I still used `f.seekg()`, I incidentally got a completed line.@JesperJuhl

Comment: Side note (not relevant to your issue, just wanted to mention it), see [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 1):

Remember to specify the open mode, e.g. `ios::binary`.

I think I have found the problem.
When I open the file, I should specific the mode, e.g., `ios::binary`.
Without that specification, the `offset` which `tellg()` returns may be not accurate under some conditions.

So I change

```c
fstream f(file_path);
```

to

```c
fstream f(file_path, ios::in | ios::binary);
```

And the value of `tellg()` gets smaller, which works for me.

Comment: Ohh, that actually makes sense. I got different results than you since the file got interpreted differently on Linux and Windows. But, as a binary file, there's no difference - it's all just bytes. Damn, should have cought that.

Comment: Hhh, really appreciate for your test which leads me to pay attention to the offset. Thanks!@JesperJuhl